# How would one verify that the public key from WhatsApp's servers belongs to the person I expect it to?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, whatsapp

WhatsApp had recently announced end-to-end encryption on all communications. While that's an impressive move, I still have a big open question mark.

The articles and [this white paper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf) suggest that the public key, upon generation, gets stored on the server. When I want to speak to another person, I ask the WhatsApp server for their public key, and use that in communication.
That same white paper says this about key verification:

> WhatsApp users
>   additionally have the option to verify the keys of the other users
>   with whom they are communicating so that they are able to confirm that
>   an unauthorized third party (or WhatsApp) has not initiated a
>   man-in-the-middle attack. This can be done by scanning a QR code, or
>   by comparing a 60-digit number.

Oh, that's nice, how are those things generated?

> The QR code contains:
>
> 1. A version.
> 2. The user identifier for both parties.
> 3. The full 32-byte public Identity Key for both parties.
>
> When either user scans the other’s QR code, the keys are compared to ensure that
>   what is in the QR code matches the Identity Key as retrieved from the
>   server.

But... those are all details that the server knows, and requires nothing special from the other person (it doesn't mention the QR being signed). How about the 60 digit number?

> The 60-digit number is computed by concatenating the two 30-digit
>   numeric fingerprints for each user’s Identity Key. To calculate a
>   30-digit numeric fingerprint:
>
> 1. Iteratively SHA-512 hash the public Identity Key and user identifier 5200 times.
> 2. Take the first 30 bytes of the final hash output.
> 3. Split the 30-byte result into six 5-byte chunks.
> 4. Convert each 5-byte chunk into 5 digits by interpreting each 5-byte chunk as a big-endian unsigned integer and reducing it modulo
>      100000.
> 5. Concatenate the six groups of five digits into thirty digits.

Again, those are details the server can easily calculate and present to me as valid verification data.

---

Am I misunderstanding this, or is there no real way of verifying that the public key I'm talking to belongs to the person I think it does?

Comment: TL;DR: You download and cache the public key and a MitM attack requires the attacker to swap out public keys. So he can re-encrypt traffic but then the public key of the other party won't match the one you see which you can detect by verifying the (QR) code in person.

Comment: I don't understand how your objections are a problem. Can you outline the attack scenario you're concerned about?

Comment: @Volker I'm not sure myself, I'm a security enthusiast, not an expert. But isn't it bad that you can't reliably verify the key's correctness?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: What do you mean, you can't? You meet your friend and compare the security codes. If they match, you know you're actually communicating with your friend and not a man in the middle. If they don't, someone is evesdropping. What would a potential attack look like here?

Comment: @Volker But you are comparing public keys, keys that could originate from the server, and not from your friend's device.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It doesn't matter. Public keys are public, not secret. The attacker is free to know the public keys. But to intercept the communication he also needs the private key. I still don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 4):

Both the QR code and the 60 digit number need to be verified "out of band", for example:

- Saying the number out loud in a telephone call
- Meeting in person and scanning the QR code directly from the other device

Comment: All of this is rendered useless when closed-source WhatsApp just copies your private keys to their server. =o)

Comment: Yes, but the QR can be generated entirely from server-known information, you can't trust the QR being generated from the locally generated public key alone.